# How can I redirect a request to the record of the current_user and mask route at same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

Each `User has_one :family_tree`.

So the family_tree route looks like a normal `resources :family_trees`.

I have a route that looks like this:

```
  get "dashboard/my_tree" => "dashboard#my_tree", as: :my_tree, path: "/my_tree"
```

What I want to happen is, whenever someone goes to `family_tree/:my_id` they should be redirected to (or just shown the URL path for) `/my_tree`. Please note: that the `:my_id` is the ID of the `family_tree` that belongs to the `current_user`.

The issue is that my `FamilyTree#Show` controller action looks like this:

```
  def show
    @user = @family_tree.user
    @memberships = @family_tree.memberships
    @memberships_grouped_by_relations = @memberships.includes(user: :family_tree).group_by(&:relation)
    @nodes = @family_tree.nodes

    render "dashboard/my_tree"
  end
```

And my `DashboardController#MyTree` looks like this:

```
  def my_tree
    @user = current_user
    @family_tree = @user.family_tree
    @memberships_grouped_by_relations = @family_tree.memberships.group_by(&:relation)    
  end
```

Both work, but I just don't know how to mask the URL of `family_tree/51` to redirect to `my_tree`. But, obviously, I don't want all requests to `family_tree/:id` to show `/my_tree`. E.g. if the family_tree associated with the `current_user` is `id=51`, then when that user goes to `family_tree/52`, that URL should say 'family_tree/52`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# app/controllers/family_trees_controller.rb
class FamilyTreesController < ApplicationController

  # family_tree GET    /family_trees/:id(.:format)
  #
  # @note !IMPORTANT
  #   Should only have 1 or 2 instance vars per action
  def show
    # @user = @family_tree.user #=> not needed, available on the primary instance var (@family_tree)
    if current_user == family_tree.user
      redirect_to my_tree_index_path
    else
      # @memberships = @family_tree.memberships
      # @memberships_grouped_by_relations #=> too long of a name!
      #                                       There is currently only one grouped membership,
      #                                       why not rename it to:
      @grouped_memberships = family_tree.memberships.includes(user: :family_tree).group_by(&:relation)
      # Shouldn't create another ivar if it's available on the primary ivar
      # @nodes = @family_tree.nodes
    end
  end

  protected

  def family_tree
    @family_tree ||= FamilyTree.find(params[:id])
  end
end

# app/controllers/my_trees_controller.rb
class MyTreesController < ApplicationController

  # my_tree_index GET    /my_tree(.:format)
  def index
    @grouped_memberships = current_user.family_tree.memberships.group_by(&:relation)
  end
end
```

And the routes:

```
# config/routes.rb
My::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :family_trees
  resources :my_tree, only: :index
end
```

Comment: This is definitely one solution, but I am looking for something that keeps it all within the `FamilyTree` controller. i.e. the preferable option would be doing something in the `routes.rb`.